# String concatenation in rust and borrowing

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

I have been learning rust recently.

And I stumbled upon a snippet that is really bugging me.

Why does this work

```
    fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1 + &s2;
    println!("{}",s3)
}
```

And this does not?

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = &s1 + s2;
    println!("{}",s3)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, it's because `String` implements [`Add<&str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20str%3E) and [`Deref<Target=str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref). So the compiler can rewrite your first example, `s1 + &s2`, into `s1.add (s2.deref())`.

However neither `&String` nor `&str` implement `Add`, so the compiler can't rewrite `&s1 + …` into `(&s1).add (…)`.

From a language design standpoint, this choice was made because `s1 + …` may be done without allocation if there is enough space already allocated after the current contents of `s1`, but `&s1 + …` would always require an allocation and it was decided to make that allocation explicit. If you want to keep using the original `s1` after the operation, you need to either clone it explicitly:

```
let s3 = s1.clone() + &s2;
```

or if performance is really that critical, you need to pre-allocate enough memory to hold the result:

```
let s3 = String::with_capacity (s1.len() + s2.len()) + &s1 + &s2;
```